# "Unexpected character while parsing path: t"

Tags: json, json.net

Since upgrading to Json.net 6.0.1, I'm no longer able to make a request for `.SelectToken("$type")`.  Does anyone know if this is a breaking change?

The following code works with an older version:

```
var json = {"$type" : "test", "property1" : "value1"}
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

// this line works
var property1 = obj.SelectToken("property1");

// this line throws in 6.0.1 - "Unexpected character while parsing path: t"
var docType = obj.SelectToken("$type");
```

Comment: wont this work ? json["$type"]

Comment: Yes, that does work. Any idea is this is a known breaking change to SelectToken?

Comment: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/25193

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in [Json.Net 6.0 release 3](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/121470).  I was able to confirm this by downloading the 6.0.2 and 6.0.3 releases through NuGet and testing locally with each one using the code posted in the question.  6.0.2 throws an exception while 6.0.3 (and later) does not.